# image not getting uploaded in django via model form but getting added from the admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

So in my django project , I have a page where user can fill details about his profile via a form.

The form is as follows :

```
class VendorProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vendor
        fields = ['name', 'address', 'pincode', 'phone', 'email', 'image1', 'image2', 'image3', 'image4']
```

The model 'Vendor' to which the form is referring to is as follows :

```
class Vendor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    pincode = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=200)
    image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='shop_images/', blank=True, null=True)
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='shop_images/', blank=True, null=True)
    image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='shop_images/', blank=True, null=True)
    image4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='shop_images/', blank=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='vendor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The view used is as follows:

```
@login_required
    def vendor_profile_details(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = VendorProfileForm(request.POST)
    
            if form.is_valid():
                vendor = form.save(commit=False)
                vendor.created_by = request.user
                vendor.save()
                return redirect('vendor_admin')
        else:
            form = VendorProfileForm()
    
        return render(request, 'vendor_profile_details.html', {'form': form})
```

And the template used for the frontend part 'vendor_profile_details.html' is as follows:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Profile details | {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1 class="title">Finish your profile</h1>

    <form method="post" action="." method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form.as_p }}

        <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
                <button class="button is-dark is-uppercase" type="submit">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <hr>

{% endblock %}
```

In the main project urls.py file of the project where I include all the urls of the various other apps ,  I have done the settings for the static upload

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('vendors/', include('vendor.urls')),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I have properly defined the media folder in the settings.py file

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR/'media/'
```

Despite doing all this , my images are not getting uploaded into the media folder via the form .
However when I go into the admin panel and directly add the images from there , the images get uploaded into the media folder successfully . Why is this issue occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide [request.FILES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) as argument to your form, as well:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VendorProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files

> In practice, you will usually specify request.FILES as the source of
> file data (just like you use request.POST as the source of form data):
>
> ```
> # Bound form with an image field, data from the request
> >>> f = ContactFormWithMugshot(request.POST, request.FILES)
> ```